# Am odd expression?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

As any mathematician will tell you there are many expressions involving X.
X can mark the spot. XX is male. XXX is naughty. XXXX is naughtier still.
But how can XXXXX be M?

Comment: I would have thought XX is female

Comment: I would have thought XXX is beer.

Comment: @WeatherVane And [XXXX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXXX_(beer))...

Comment: Is the title purposely spelled wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

XXXXX is M if

> We read it as 'X x X x X' - i.e. 'X times X times X', which in roman numerals is 10 x 10 x 10 = 1000
>
> and 1000 is M in roman numerals!